# Jenkins throws 502 Bad Gateway upon pushing build status to Bitbucket via Bitbucket Server Notifier Plugin

Tags: jenkins, networking, proxy, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

- I have my repo on Bitbucket Server (stash).
- I have single job on Jenkins server.
- I have Bitbucket Server Notifier Plugin for Jenkins
  installed and configured (to push build status to Bitbucket).
- I can telnet to my Bitbucket Server URL from Jenkins machine.
- I can access my Bitbucket Server URL via the browser from Jenkins machine.

However Bitbucket Server Notifier fails with error 502: Bad gateway - DNS error:

```
Notifying Bitbucket at "https://my.bitbucket.server.url"
Failed to notify Bitbucket for commit g55f45daf0ce678588171ef45g55h34g44 (<html><head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body><h1>DNS error</h1>
<p>DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist)<br><br>Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.<br></p>
<!--Zscaler/6.0--></body></html>
)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I feel like it might be proxy issue. Can anyone advice please?